# How to mock up Blog and Post when one Blog contains many Posts

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, entity-framework-core

Say we have

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

I want to seed data for `Blog` and `Post` in unit test. However Blog contains Posts and Post contains Blog.

**[EDIT]**

I want to pass the `DbContext` to the controller. Therefore I have to mock up `DbContext` and `DbSet`. For the `DbSet`, I need to seed some dummy data.

For example:
In asp.net mvc controller

```
public IActionResult GetBlog(int id)
{
    Blog blog = _context.Blog.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BlogId == id);
    return View(Blog);
}
```

In the test

```
[Fact]
public void Get_blog_1_returns_google()
{
    // Act
    var result = _controller.GetBlog(1) as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsType(typeof(Blog), result.ViewData.Model);
    Blog model = (Blog)result.ViewData.Model;
    Assert.Equal("google", model.Url);
}
```

But I have to seed data for the test first.

```
public class BlogControllerTest
{
    private BloggingContext _context;
    private BlogController _controller;

    public BlogControllerTest()
    {
        // Seed data
        _context.Blog.Add(new Blog()
        {
            BlogId = 1,
            Url = "google",
            // how about Post
        });
        //..other code...
    }
    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

How to mock up them?

Comment: What Unit Test you trying to write? What specific behavior you trying to test apart from mocking aspects you mentioned. It would easier to answer your question if you can show the Unit Test you trying to write.

Comment: @Spock,  Please see my edit.

Comment: Why do you not create a new Post in BlogControllerTest?

Comment: @JeroenHeier, I can. But you know Post includes Blog as well, So it is sort of cycle of dependency. That is my question I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should create some abstractions to make your `DbContext` easier to mock/test

```cs
public interface IDbContext : IDisposable {
    int SaveChanges();
}

public interface IBloggingContext : IDbContext {
    DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; }
    DbSet<Post> Posts { get; }
}
```

With these abstractions you can then have your concrete `BloggingContext` implemented.

```cs
public class BloggingContext : DbContext, IBloggingContext {
    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming your `BlogController` is using constructor injection...

```cs
public class BlogController : Controller {
    private IBloggingContext _context;

    public BlogController(IBloggingContext bloggingContext) {
        this._context = bloggingContext;
    }

    public IActionResult GetBlog(int id) {
        Blog blog = _context.Blogs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BlogId == id);
        return View(blog);
    }
}
```

You can now use a mocking framework like **Moq** to mock the `IBloggingContext` to return fake/mocked instances of `Blog` and `Post`.

```cs
public class BlogControllerTest {
    private IBloggingContext _context;
    private BlogController _controller;

    public BlogControllerTest() {

        //creating seed objects
        var post = new Post() {
            PostId = 1,
            Title = "Some title",
            Content = "post contemt"
        };

        var blog = new Blog() {
            BlogId = 1,
            Url = "google",
            Posts = new List<Post>() { post }
        };

        //associating blog with post
        post.Blog = blog;
        post.BlogId = blog.BlogId;

        var blogsMock = new List<Blog>() { blog }.AsDbSetMock();
        var postsMock = new List<Post>() { post }.AsDbSetMock();

        var contextMock = new Mock<IBloggingContext>();
        contextMock.Setup(m => m.Blogs).Returns(blogsMock.Object);
        contextMock.Setup(m => m.Posts).Returns(postsMock.Object);

        _context = contextMock.Object;
        _controller = new BlogController(_context);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Get_blog_1_returns_google() {
        // Act
        var result = _controller.GetBlog(1) as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsType(typeof(Blog), result.ViewData.Model);
        Blog model = (Blog)result.ViewData.Model;
        Assert.Equal("google", model.Url);
    }

}
```